# $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{f(x)}{(1-ax)^{4}}dx=F(a)\,(1-a)^{-3},$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{a\rightarrow 1^{-}} F(a)$ does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have the following question:

It can be checked that $$\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{(1-ax)^{4}}dx \sim (1-a)^{-3},\text{ for }0<a<1.$$

Here by $F(a)\sim G(a)$, I mean that there are positive constants $c_{1},c_{2}$ s.t. $c_{1}\leq\dfrac{F(a)}{G(a)}\leq c_{2}$, for any $a\in (0,1)$.

My question: I would like to construct a non-negative function $f(x)$ (does not depend on $a$) such that $$\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{f(x)}{(1-ax)^{4}}dx=F(a)\,(1-a)^{-3},$$
here $F$ is some bounded function on $(0,1)$ s.t. $\displaystyle\lim_{a\rightarrow 1^{-}} F(a)$ does not exist; for example, something like $F(a)=\sin^{2}(\dfrac{1}{1-a})$.

Could someone come up with an idea to contruct such a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ A(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(1-a x)^4} .$$
Note
$$ (1-a)^3A(a) \to \frac13, \quad (a \nearrow 1). $$
Now, for any $0 \le b < 1$, we have
$$ \frac1{A(a)}\int_0^b  \frac{dx}{(1-a x)^4} \, dx \to 0, \quad (a \nearrow 1) ,$$
and also
$$ \frac1{A(a)}\int_c^1  \frac{dx}{(1-ax)^4} \, dx \to 0, \quad (c\nearrow 1) .$$
Now we choose sequences $0 < a_n < 1$, and $0 < b_n < c_n < 1$ as follows.  Given $a_1,\dots,a_n$, $b_1,\dots,b_n$, $c_1,\dots,c_n$:

1. choose $b_{n+1} > c_n$;
2. choose $a_{n+1} > 1-\frac1n$ such that
   $$\frac1{A(a_{n+1})}\int_0^{b_{n+1}}  \frac{dx}{(1-a_{n+1} x)^4} \, dx < \frac1n ;$$
3. choose $c_{n+1} > b_{n+1}$ such that
   $$ \frac1{A(a_{n+1})}\int_{c_{n+1}}^1  \frac{dx}{(1-a_{n+1}x)^4} \, dx  < \frac1n .$$

Then $a_n \nearrow 1$, and if
$$ B_n = \int_{b_n}^{c_n} \frac{dx}{(1-a_nx)^4} $$
then
$$ \frac{|A_{a_n} - B_n|}{A_{a_n}} \to 0 ,$$
and the intervals $[b_n, c_n]$ are disjoint.

Let $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be such that $f_{[b_{2n},c_{2n}]} = 1$ and $f_{[b_{2n+1},c_{2n+1}]} = 0$.
Let
$$ G(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{f(x) \, dx}{(1-ax)^4} , \qquad F(a) = (1-a)^3 G(a) .$$
Then
\begin{align} |G(a_n) - I_{\text{$n$ even}}A_{a_n} | 
&= \left|\int_{[0,1] \setminus [b_n,c_n]} \frac{(f(x)-I_{\text{$n$ even}}) \, dx}{(1-a_n x)^4} \right|
\\&\le \int_{[0,1] \setminus [b_n,c_n]} \frac{dx}{(1-a_n x)^4}
\\& = |A_{a_n} - B_n|
\end{align}
that is
$$ \frac{G(a_n)}{A_{a_n}} \to I_{\text{$n$ even}}, \quad (n\to\infty) .$$
So $F(a_{2n}) \to \frac13$, but $F(a_{2n+1}) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Hi, I could not understand your answer. Why $F(a_{2n})\rightarrow \dfrac{1}{3}$?

Comment: What is $I_{n\;\text{even}}$?

Comment: $I_P$ is the indicator function of property $P$.  1 if $P$ holds, zero otherwise.

Comment: I think that it would be $ \frac{A_n}{(1-a_n)^{-3}} \to \frac13, \quad (n \to \infty).$

Comment: Yes, I just fixed it.  And a few other typos.

Comment: Why do we have $|A_n - B_n| \le \frac 1n A_n ?$. It's not clear such sequences exist.

Comment: @Hana what about say $b_n$ such that $\int_0^{b_n}\frac{dx}{(1-a_n x)^4} =\frac{1}{2n} A_n$ and  $c_n$ s.t.$\int_{c_n}^1\frac{dx}{(1-a_n x)^4} =\frac{1}{2n} A_n$? Wouldn't those work?

Comment: Yes they would.  I also added more explanation to the text.

Comment: OK, I worked it some more.  Are you ready to accept my answer?

Comment: @ I really appreciate your effort. Could you give an explanation for $|G(a_n) - I_{\text{$n$ even}}A_{a_n} | \le |A_{a_n} - B_n|$.

Comment: OK, how is that?

Comment: @Stephen Thks, How did you train for such great intuition? I struggled to follow your idea.

Comment: I guess I pushed myself hard as a kid to think about hard Math problems.